# Use subsonic 3.0 to work with stored procedures

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Hi I just downloaded subsonic 3.0 and I want to work with stored procedures.  I don't know which template to choose:  ActiveRecord or LinqTemplates.  I don't really know the difference.  I know that I don't want to deal with Linq code.  I just want subsonic to generate classes based on tables and also their relationships (if possible) and generate code to interface with stored procedures.

I couldn't find a lot of info on the subsonicproject site.  I don't know which template folder to drag into my project, and which _settings.tt file to change.  Under the T4 templates, there are four folders: ActiveRecord, LinqTemplates, SubSonic.TemplatesVB, TemplateProviders.  I don't know which one to deal with for my situation.  Can somebody post step by step instructions please, or point me to a page that already does?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using the Activerecord template, wich generates a class with every stored procedure in the database.  The settings.tt files depend on wich database you're working (SQL Server, SQLite, MySQL..)  There is a straightforward instruction to configure the Activerecord templates: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord